# Could not get the number of counts using MongoDB and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need query to fetch the total count as per key value of document by matching some value from array using MongoDB. I am explaining my document and Input below.

```
dataArr=[
    {'login_id':9937229853,'location':'Delhi'},
    {'login_id':9937229854,'location':'JK'}
]
```

My document is given below.

> feedback:

```
{
   login_id:9937229853,
   code: PTP,
   remark:'Hello'
 },
 {
   login_id:9937229853,
   code: PTP,
   remark:'Hii'
 },
{
   login_id:9937229853,
   code: CB,
   remark:'aaaaa'
 },
{
   login_id:9937229854,
   code: PTP,
   remark:'jjjjj'
 },
{
   login_id:9937229854,
   code: CB,
   remark:'dddd'
 }
```

The above is my collection. Here I need as per user input login_id present inside array will match with document and the total count will be fetch as per document key and value. My expected output is given below. I am explaining my code below.

```
for(var i=0;i<dataArr.length;i++){
                    var login=dataArr[i]['login_id'];
                    //console.log('cdocs',dataArr[i]['login_id']);
                    Feedback.collection.count({login_id:dataArr[i]['login_id']},function(cerr,cdocs){
                       console.log('cdocs',login);
                        if (!cerr) {
                            if(cdocs > 0){
                              // console.log('login',cdocs);
                                db.collection.aggregate([
                                    {
                                        $match: {
                                            keywords: { $not: {$size: 0} }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    { $unwind: "$keywords" },
                                    {
                                        $group: {
                                            _id: {$toLower: '$keywords'},
                                            count: { $sum: 1 }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        $match: {
                                            login_id: login
                                        }
                                    }
                                ])
                                .toArray((err,docs)=>{
                                    if (!err) {
                                     // console.log('count::',docs);
                                        finalArr=docs;

                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
                var data={'status':'success','data':finalArr}
                res.send(data);
```

I need the expected result like below.

```
finalArr=[
    {'login_id':9937229853,'location':'Delhi','PTP':2,'CB':1,'remark':3},
    {'login_id':9937229854,'location':'JK','PTP':1,'CB':1,'remark':2},
]
```

But using my code I am getting the blank output. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all this with a single aggregate operation. The first pipeline stage would be filtering the documents in the collection using the input array. You would need to map that array to just a list of ids though in order to use the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) query operator i.e.

```
const ids = dataArr.map(({ login_id }) => login_id)
```

which can then be used in the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline as

```
const match = { '$match': { 'login_in': { '$in': ids } } }
```

The next pipeline step will then use the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage to group the above filtered documents by the `login_id` key

```
const allGroup = { '$group': {
    '_id': {
        'login_id': '$login_id',
        'code': '$code',
        'remark': '$remark'
    },
    'count': { '$sum': 1 }
} }
```

Another [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage to get the remarks counts as a list of key/value documents

```
const remarksGroup = { '$group': {
    '_id': {
        'login_id': '$_id.login_id',
        'code': '$_id.code'
    },
    'remarks': {
        '$push': {
            'k': '$_id.remark',
            'v': '$count'
        }
    },
    'count': { '$sum': 1 }
} }
```

Get the code counts with a similar structure as above

```
const codeGroup = { '$group': {
    '_id': '$_id.login_id',
    'codes': {
        '$push': {
            'k': '$_id.code',
            'v': '$count'
        }
    },
    'remarks': { '$first': '$remarks' }
} }
```

You would need a final pipeline to convert the key/value pairs arrays to objects using [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/), merge the objects into one using [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) and replace the root document with the merged docs using [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/):

```
const projections = { '$replaceRoot': {
    'newRoot': {
        '$mergeObjects': [
            { 'login_id': '$_id' },
            { '$arrayToObject': '$codes' },
            { '$arrayToObject': '$remarks' }
        ]
    }
} }
```

Your full aggregate pipeline operation would be:

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const ids = dataArr.map(({ login_id }) => login_id)
        const match = { '$match': { 'login_in': { '$in': ids } } }
        const allGroup = { '$group': {
            '_id': {
                'login_id': '$login_id',
                'code': '$code',
                'remark': '$remark'
            },
            'count': { '$sum': 1 }
        } }
        const remarksGroup = { '$group': {
            '_id': {
                'login_id': '$_id.login_id',
                'code': '$_id.code'
            },
            'remarks': {
                '$push': {
                    'k': '$_id.remark',
                    'v': '$count'
                }
            },
            'count': { '$sum': 1 }
        } }
        const codeGroup = { '$group': {
            '_id': '$_id.login_id',
            'codes': {
                '$push': {
                    'k': '$_id.code',
                    'v': '$count'
                }
            },
            'remarks': { '$first': '$remarks' }
        } }
        const projections = { '$$replaceRoot': {
            'newRoot': {
                '$mergeObjects': [
                    { 'login_id': '$_id' },
                    { '$arrayToObject': '$codes' },
                    { '$arrayToObject': '$remarks' }
                ]
            }
        } }

        const result = await Feedback.aggregate([
            match,
            allGroup,
            remarksGroup,
            codeGroup,
            projections
        ])

        /* get the location key */
        const data = result.map(item => {
            const [{ location }, ...rest] = dataArr.filter(d => d.location_id === item.location_id)
            return { location, ...item }
        })

        console.log(data)
        res.send(data)

    } catch (err) {
        // handle error

    }
})()
```

Comment: did not get `{ location }, ...rest` and `{ location, ...item }`.

Comment: Does `result` from the aggregate operation give you the correct counts?

Comment: @subhra This is called [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_the_rest_of_an_array_to_a_variable) which allows you to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.